# update magento 1.9.1.0 to 1.9.2.0

Tags: upgrade

i want to update update magento 1.9.1.0 to 1.9.2.0

i google most of link here but could not find proper answer, i am bit stucked how to proceed

1: i tried to updated all modules using "Magento connect manager"
but i had issue

i console i see some conflict error

also after process is completed it keep on redirecting me to download page

i tried this two three times same error ,

i need help the proper way to update modules

Comment: visit the link:-http://duntuk.com/magento-upgrade

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the steps I would recommend for any incremental Magento upgrade. You will need full command line access to your server.

**TEST, test, test**

Carry out the first upgrade on your development server. I use a VMWare virtual server so that I can take a snapshot of the running 1.9.1.x system before the upgrade. Then I can always revert to the previous version if I need to, or if I need to run the upgrade again.

**Note that this upgrade method will only work when you are certain that all Magento core code, template and locale files/templates have not been modified.**

**BACKUP, backup, backup**

- Take a backup of your Magento database.
- Take a backup of your 1.9.1.x installation folder.

**Installation**

Obtain the Magento CE 1.9.2.x source from the Magento download site
https://www.magentocommerce.com/download

Unzip the source files into a working folder. This will create a magento folder containing the 1.9.2.x source.

Disable cache

Take your shop offline

- stop your cron tasks
- put the shop into maintenance mode

  - touch /home/pathtomagentoroot/maintenance.flag
  - or if use n98magerun n98-magerun.phar sys:maintenance

Copy the 1.9.2.x source over your 1.9.1.x installation

I like to use rsync to do this :

```
rsync -avI –exclude=app/etc/local.xml –exclude=app/etc/config.xml –exclude=index.php –exclude=.htaccess ./magento/ /home/www/magento/
```

Where /home/www/magento is the path to the 1.9.1.x installation. There are other ways of copying the files, the main thing to consider is not to overwrite any config files you may have modified, in the above rsync command I am excluding config.xml, index.php and .htaccess because I know I have some custom configuration commands in these files.

Reset Magento permissions

Update modman modules (if you use modman)

- modman update-all --force

Put shop online

- rm /home/pathtomagentoroot/maintenance.flag

restart cron

**Test**

- login to admin
- refresh caches
- test frontend
- test login
- test orders
- test new customer registration

**Test again**

Taken from http://blog.gaiterjones.com/upgrade-magento-ce-1-9-1-x-to-1-9-2-0/

Answer (score -1):

What you could try to do is the following:

1. Clean your var/sessions and var/cache folder
2. Reindex your Magento store via SSH

   ```
   php ./shell/indexer.php -reindexall
   ```
3. Download the latest version of Magento from the magento site and
   overwrite your installation.

**Keep in in mind to always make a backup first!**

Comment: This is pretty bad advice as you fail to provide any detailed process or information, an upgrade to a live Magento shop is business critical, getting it wrong can cost money. It should always be thoroughly tested on a development/test server first.

Comment: @paj can u please guide

Comment: I take it you mean a Magento core upgrade, and not just modules. I have added an answer to help upgrading Magento core to 1.9.2.x